# Top margin of first child and bottom margin of last child

Tags: html, css, margin

HTML

```
<div class="lev1">level1</div>
<div class="lev2wrap">
<div class="lev2">level2</div>
<div class="lev2">level2</div>
<div class="lev2">level2</div>
<div class="lev2">level2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.lev1{
  background:lightblue;
}
.lev2wrap{
  background:gold;
}
.lev2{
  background:#999999;
  margin:10px 0;
}
```

Why does the first instance of `lev2` not have a top margin of `10px`, and why does the last instance of `lev2` not have a bottom margin of `10px`?

Instead, `lev2wrap` has a top and bottom margin, but that's not a CSS instruction.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/j5qj4c36/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

> Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed)
>   into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined
>   into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing.
>
> Margin collapsing occurs in three basic cases:
>
> - Adjacent siblings
> - **Parent and first/last child**
> - Empty blocks

To have the margin of lev2wrap show, add overflow: auto to it:

```
.lev2wrap {
  background: gold;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/j5qj4c36/1/)**